# Access info from outer page from within embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have written a page, served from the domain banana.example.com. I own that domain. The purpose of the page is for it to be embedded in pages from mango.example.com, which I don't own. (Same "big domain," but not *exactly* the same domain.) This works fine. I give the people at Mango the URL and they can embed my Banana page in an iframe on their site.

I would like for my page to display slightly different content depending on exactly which page on mango.example.com it is being embedded.

If I write:

```
console.log(window.parent.window.location);
```

I get the full URL printed to the console as a Location object, but I can't access any of that object's properties (e.g., href, pathname) or use either implied or explicit methods to stringify the location object.

Is there any way that I can get information about the page that my page is being embedded in? URL, title, anything? (For the purposes of this question, please assume that I only have authority over banana.example.com and can't ask the folks at mango.example.com to do anything.)

Comment: Do you have access to the embedded page script, or any extra configuration? Cuz you can pass the current URL through query params or POST data.

Comment: I can write JavaScript (or PHP, if that would help) on the "banana" side. Not clear how query params or POST data play into this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Then forget, you can do nothing. When I referred to POST data I meant the POST request body, or the URL query parameters, before the fragment #, i.e.: `http:blah.com?p1&p2=blah&url=encodedURL`

Comment: @handoncloud you told the op he/she can do nothing. You are mistaken. postMessage can be used to remedy the situation in case the owner of the other site can be convinced to cooperate.

Comment: @LajosArpad Wrong, the owner won't. I said the op author can do nothing unless contact.

Comment: @handoncloud "Wrong, the owner won't". What??? The op needs to contact the owner, not the other way around. " I said the op author can do nothing unless contact." Nope, you did not say that. You were asking about the possibility to access resources and when the answer was a "no", you said there is no solution.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, he needs, but this won't confirm the contact will be successful. Okay, it was a mistake-> I didn't say that, but contact isn't a solution. You don't know the current situation and the possibilities, because the answer isn't specific for the embedded page provider, and you ask the op author nothing about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the browser's [CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). A solution for this problem would be to post a message to the outer page requesting for information, which, in turn would post a response to your `iframe` which will have a handler for that. Read about `postMessage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Note that in case you are not controlling the outer page you will not be able to solve the problem like this. You will need to convince the owner of Mango to receive your message where the `iframe` is requesting for information and to use `postMessage` to respond to it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: Oops! This is a comment

Comment: @handoncloud I suppose your comment refers to the length of the answer. The answer fully answered the question and in such a situation I would be very surprised if adding more length would make this a "better" answer. A short full answer is superior than a long full answer if you ask me.

Comment: @anaximander yes, I can confirm that you are right. I was in a similar situation as you before and had to find out this on my own. It was not a good experience. If my answer solved your problem then you might consider accepting it.

Comment: @LajosArpad Okay, but I've made a canvas answer some months ago and they said the same thing, so this answer doesn't solve the actual problem, it's a recommendation, so actually a comment.

Comment: @handoncloud it is not a comment. I have solved my issue with this approach. This is the only possible solution. If you fail to negotiate with the owner of the other site, then you cannot apply this, but it does not invalidate this solution.

Comment: @LajosArpad It's a comment, because your answer can't solve the op's issue, you don't know the actual situation and possibilities.

Comment: @handoncloud you are obviously wrong. My answer is a way to solve the problem. It involves reaching out to the owner of the other site, which is the only possible solution. The level of your comments does not motivate me to allocate too much time for this conversation, nor your rating. If you are going to show a better level, then I will surely answer to you, otherwise I cannot promise that.

Comment: @LajosArpad No, it's not. postMessage() won't help in anything, only the owner may provide this. Then it's easy, don't mention postMessage() because it's mango.example.com owner side, not yours/op side. Your answer won't solve anything. Contact is the most obvious thing, and may not be successful. Your answer isn't valid until the question specifies how does the embedded page provider work.

Comment: And it's quite obvious it's CORS problem (the banana.example.com can't access mango.example.com), it's already said.